# Removing leading zeros from alphanumeric characters in R

Tags: regex, string, r, character, gsub

I have a character vector `d` with alphanumeric characters

```
d <- c("012309 template", "separate 00340", "00045", "890 098", "3405 garage", "matter00908")

d
[1] "012309 template" "separate 00340"  "00045"           "890 098"         "3405 garage"     "matter00908"
```

How can I remove the leading zeros from all the numbers in R?
 `as.numeric` will remove all leading zeros only in numeric or integer vectors. I have tried `gsub` with `regex` but could not get the desired results.

The expected output is as follows

```
out <- c("12309 template", "seperate 340", "45", "890 98", "3405 garage", "matter908")
out
[1] "12309 template" "seperate 340"   "45"             "890 98"         "3405 garage"    "matter908"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind to eliminate 0 unless preceded by a digit:

```
> d <- c("100001", "012309 template", "separate 00340", "00045", "890 098", "3405 garage", "matter00908")
> gsub("(?<![0-9])0+", "", d, perl = TRUE)
[1] "100001"         "12309 template" "separate 340"   "45"            
[5] "890 98"         "3405 garage"    "matter908"
```

Another way using regex:

```
> gsub("(^|[^0-9])0+", "\\1", d, perl = TRUE)
[1] "100001"         "12309 template" "separate 340"   "45"            
[5] "890 98"         "3405 garage"    "matter908"     
>
```

Comment: This is also removing multiple zeros within numeric strings eg. 100001 to 101.

Comment: @Crops Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the solution utilizing `stri_replace_all_regex` from the [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package:

```
d <- c("012309 template", "separate 00340", "00045",
       "890 098", "3405 garage", "matter00908")
library("stringi")
stri_replace_all_regex(d, "\\b0*(\\d+)\\b", "$1")
## [1] "12309 template" "separate 340"   "45"             "890 98"
## [5] "3405 garage"    "matter00908"
```

Explanation: We are matching all sequences of digits within word boundaries (`\b`). Trailing zeros are matched greedily (`0+`). The remaining digits (`\d` denotes any digit,
`\d+` denotes their non-empty sequence) are captured within a group (`(...)`). Then we replace all such matches with the group-captured stuff only.

If you'd also wish to remove 0s within words (as in your example), just omit `\b` and call:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(d, "0*(\\d+)", "$1")
## [1] "12309 template" "separate 340"   "45"             "890 98"
## [5] "3405 garage"    "matter908"
```

Comment: What about the '\\d+' ?

Comment: edited: *`\d` denotes any digit, `\d+` denotes their non-empty sequence*